# Books on optimizing and refactoring SQL stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can you please recommend resources to write efficient store procedures, refactor and optimize them?

Thank you.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219025) by [Grant Fritchey](http://www.amazon.com/Grant-Fritchey/e/B002F8BIAQ/ref=ntt_dp_epwbk_0) is a great tool for advancing your performance tuning skills.  He is renowned in the SQL Server community as an expert.

Comment: This might also help on the refactoring front: http://databaserefactoring.com/